# What is the canonical way to write a for-loop macro?

Tags: tex-core, programming, loops

At a basic level TeX does not provide a for-loop construct, but allows tail-end recursion, however Knuth defined `\loop` in the plain macros. Coders have been coming with variations of their own ever since.

The `ifthen` package provides the `whiledo` loop and there is a `forloop` macro. TikZ   provides similarly a `foreach` macro.

Is there a canonical way to write a `forloop` in LaTeX, TeX and friends. How would you write the following?

```
\def\triangle#1{{\def\bull{}%
\count1=0
\loop
   \edef\bull{$\bullet$\bull}
   \ifnum\count1<#1
      \advance\count1 by 1
      \centerline{\bull}
      \vskip-7.7pt
      \repeat
      \vskip 7.7pt\relax}}
```

which will produce a triangle made of dots

```
        *
     *    *
  *     *    *
```

As typically found in programming texts, can you re-write it in a better way?

Comment: Should this be community wiki? There is no definite answer. And there are already three different “right” answers.

Comment: @caramdir I agree it should be a community wiki, I will change after 24 hours.

Comment: Changed to community wiki.

Comment: I'll CW the answers, then

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I will do it in ConTeXt:

```
\def\TRIANGLE#1%
  {\dorecurse{#1}
     {\centerline{$\dorecurse{\recurselevel}{{\bullet}}$}}}

\starttext \TRIANGLE{4} \stoptext
```

The extra braces around `\bullet` is so that is has math class ord rather than bin.

Comment: what does \recurselevel do?

Comment: `\recurselevel` is the value of the current "level". So, in the first iteration it is 1, in the second iteration it is 2, and so on. Similar to the value of `\count1` in your example.

Answer (score 7):

A couple of LaTeX3 solutions. You could do this as a replication

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_my_int
\prg_replicate:nn { 3 } {
  \int_incr:N \l_my_int
  \centerline { \prg_replicate:nn { \l_my_int } { \( \bullet \) } } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, the while-do approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_my_int
\intexpr_while_do:nn { \l_my_int < 4 } {
  \int_incr:N \l_my_int
  \centerline { \prg_replicate:nn { \l_my_int } { \( \bullet \) } } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I should add that there are limitations on the replication system in `expl3` (usually at the tens of thousands of replications!). So for a really big loop while-do might be safer.

Answer (score 6):

A LuaTeX solution could look like this:

```
\def\luatriangle#1{%
\directlua{

  for i = 1,#1 do
    tex.sprint(string.format("\\centerline{\%s}\\vskip-7.7pt", string.rep("$\\bullet$",i) ))
  end

}}
```

There is only one little problem here, because the macro contains `\\` and TeX complains about it. So the solution (and the advice) is to put all Lua code into a separate file and do something like:

```
\def\luatriangle#1{%
\directlua{
  dofile("loop.lua")
  loop(#1)
}}
```

and the Lua file (`loop.lua`):

```
function loop( count )
  for i = 1,count do
      tex.sprint(string.format("\\centerline{%s}\\vskip-7.7pt", string.rep("$\\bullet$",i) ))
  end
end
```

Not the best LuaTeX example. The ugly part is the string.format(...) line, but I think the loop part is very readable.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Plain TeX macro that's similar to the one in the question except it handles things like being used from horizontal mode or a change to `\mathsurround`.

```
\def\triangle#1{%
        \par
        \vbox{%
                \baselineskip4.3pt
                \m@th
                \toks@{}%
                \count@#1
                \loop\ifnum\count@>\z@
                        \advance\count@\m@ne
                        \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@{\bullet}}%
                        \centerline{$\the\toks@$}%
                \repeat
        }%
}
```

It should be pretty fast too. `\setbox0\vbox{\triangle{500}}` takes about .2 seconds on my laptop (an average over 1000 trials). Using 100 (about the largest that fits on a page) instead of 500 takes .007 seconds.

I also find the loop pretty readable, modulo the `@` in the names which just takes getting used to and isn't part of the loop really.

Answer (score 5):

Kees van der Laan wrote an article titled "Paradigms: Loops" which discusses several different TeX-based approaches for writing loops. See [MAPS 17](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/17/20.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, this time using Metapost. Again, this is tuned for ConTeXt, but should be easy to modify for LaTeX.

```
\startMPinclusions[+]
  vardef TRIANGLE(expr n) = 
    bullet_sep  := 5bp ;
    bullet_size := 3bp ;

    path bullet ;
    bullet := fullcircle scaled bullet_size ;

    for i := 1 upto n:
      y := -i * bullet_sep ;
      x := - (i-1)/2 * bullet_sep ;
      for j := 1 upto i :
        fill bullet shifted ( x + j*bullet_sep, y) ;
      endfor ;
    endfor ;
  enddef ;
\stopMPinclusions

\def\TRIANGLE#1{\startMPcode TRIANGLE(#1); \stopMPcode}
```

Comment: Hmm, not entirely inappropriate for the task given, but I got the impression it was just an example task and he really wanted to know about TeX-level looping...

Comment: ... of course, for all I know, that *is* TeX level :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially same as Partick's solution, but adapted to ConTeXt, and much more readable, IMO

```
\def\TRIANGLE#1{\ctxlua{third.triangle(#1)}}

\startluacode
  third = third or {}
  function third.triangle(n)
    for i=1,n do
      context.centerline(string.rep("$\\bullet$", i))
      context.blank{ "-7.7pt" }
    end
  end
\stopluacode
```

See [Context lua documents](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf) manual for details of how `context` function works.

Answer (score 2):

In OpTeX, there are expandable `\fornum` and `\foreach` loops ready for your use.

In the following example, the `\fornum` macro is used inside the `\halign` data without problems:

```
\useOpTeX
\def\triangles#1{%
   \vbox{\offinterlineskip
      \def\bullets{}
      \halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
         \fornum 1..#1\do{\global\addto\bullets{$\bullet$}\hbox{\bullets}\cr}}
   }
}

\triangles{5}

\bye
```

[image: bullets in triangle]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\begin{document}
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\intStepOneInline {1} {4} {
  \prgPrint {\centerline {\intReplicate {#1} {\(\bullet\)}}}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\end{document}
```

[image]